# Access Fragment Layout Objects From Java Not Working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to access from my code to  listview and a textview, I read a lot of posts on the internet but I didn't find anything that works for me.
I have a blank fragment like this:

```
public class MyFrag extends Fragment {

//My Code
List<String> Names = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Double> Prices = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<String> Dates =  new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> Hours =  new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> iDs =  new ArrayList<String>();
Double TotalMy = 0.00;
SimpleAdapter adapter;



public MyFrag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    //RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_frag, container, false);
    //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_frag, container, false);

    LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view = lf.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_frag, container, false);


    ListView listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
    TextView textTotalMy = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textTotalMy1);


    return view;

}
```

But when I open the fragment the application crashes.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating the same Relative Layout programmatically